# How to write integration test with Jest and Express?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, jestjs

I am trying to write integration tests with a third party microservice (Assume it is call `Service`). When a request is sent to  `Service`, it will fire a webhook. What I am trying to do is to test it the webhook parsed correctly.

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

import { handleHook} from "./hook";

export const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json(), handleHook);

describe("integration", () => {
  test("hook", async () => {
    const mock = jest.fn();
    app.post("/", (req, res) => {
      mock(req);
      res.send("");
    });

    const p = new Promise<Server>(resolve => {
      const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
        resolve(server);
      });
    });

    const server = await p;
    await upload();
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    setTimeout(() => {
      server.close();
    }, 15000);
    jest.runAllTimers();
    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(4);
  });
});
```

However, I got two problems. First, I got

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
>
> This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue

but using `--detectOpenHandles` does not show how to troubleshoot this issue.

Second, because the webhook is fire asynchronously, how can I ensure to catch all of them or wait for a period of time to timeout.

Comment: I'd recommend using [`supertest`](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) for Express API integration tests, see e.g. [these tests](https://github.com/textbook/fauxauth/blob/master/tests/integration/authorize.integration.spec.ts) in a project of mine. For mocking out the other service, you can use e.g. [`nock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock) or build a test double (like `fauxauth` itself, or [this one](https://github.com/HelpRefugees/project-flamingo/blob/master/e2e/fixtures/zapierSpy.js)) to talk to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have a problem. The test is not testing client to the server but the server can receive correct webhook (`request`) from `Service`. `supertest` seems to issue a request to express instead. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Which component are you testing? What behaviour of that component are you testing? Why does it matter *where* the request is coming from (client, webhook, another service) for the purpose of testing it?